# Django query include join

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I tried to calculate the count of the increased and decreased competitor product price which are related to products. I couldn't handle it. Can I do this by overriding `get_context_data` method? I couldn't write a query to get the data from comp_product model. How can I handle this?

Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='products')
    category   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    brand      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    product    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price      = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100)

class Comp_Product(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comp_products")
    competitor  = models.URLField()
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=100)
    change      = models.FloatField()
    stock       = models.BooleanField()
    last_update = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

View:

```
class DashboardList(ListView):

    template_name='dashboard_by_user.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return p

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        Products = context['object_list']
        context['distinct_category_count'] = Products.values('category').distinct().count()
        context['distinct_brand_count']    = Products.values('brand').distinct().count()
        context['product_count']           = Products.values('product').count()
        context['num_comp_products_with_lower_price'] = p.comp_products.filter(price__lt=p.price).count()
        context['num_comp_products_with_higher_price'] = p.comp_products.filter(price__gt=p.price).count()

        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you want to retrieve for a `Product` `p` the number of competitor products `Comp_Product` which have a lower or higher `price` then this will get you started:

```
# This is the product you're looking at, it'll be retrieved
# via the queryset and it's just randomly the first.
# If you want to do this for all products in the queryset
# you'll need to work with annotate.
p = self.queryset.first()
num_comp_products_with_lower_price = p.comp_products.filter(price__lt=p.price).count()
num_comp_products_with_higher_price = p.comp_products.filter(price__gt=p.price).count()
```

If you have `p` in your view it shouldn't be a problem to do this in `get_context_data`.

Comment: Actually, I used get_queryset() method to make the products dynamic. Thanks for your comments. I tried it, but  it doesn't work. I can't reach them from get_context_data. I edit the view class above.

Comment: Yes actually you can. You're using a `ListView` so the queryset is available as the `queryset` attribute. So you can use `self.queryset` to access it. Be careful thought that it can return multiple objects. So if you want to have lower/higher prices you'll need to work with `annotate`.

Comment: Unfortunaltely not. It gave AttributeError. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first'

Comment: This means that your queryset is empty, i.e. `Product.objects.filter()` is probably returning nothing. Are you sure you have data in the tables?

Comment: Yes, I have data in the tables. If I define p outside of the get_context_data() and inside of the get_queryset(), it gave me NameError as name 'p' is not defined. If I define it inside of the get_context_data(), it gave me AttributeError as 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first'. By the way, it gave me 'distinct_category_count', 'distinct_brand_count','product_count'